# How to Hide The Browsers toolbar using GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am trying to hide the toolbar, menubar of the browser when i run my GWT project..

For that i use the code

```
public void onModuleload(){

Window.open("/fes_1.0/", "_blank", "location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0");

}
```

but it keep on loading and opening multiple windows.

how to hide the toolbar when it loads initially in GWT..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What browser you use? Not all parameters works correctly on all browsers

> location=yes|no|1|0   Whether or not to display the address field. Opera only
>
> menubar=yes|no|1|0    Whether or not to display the menu bar
>
> toolbar=yes|no|1|0    Whether or not to display the browser toolbar. IE
>   and Firefox only

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thank you, I am using Chrome